# How to return the product of a while loop in a variable

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I am trying to fetch the product of a while loop out of my variable:

```
var firstOne = 1;
var timesBy = 0;
var result1 = function()
{
  while (timesBy < 10) {
firstOne * timesBy;
timesBy = timesBy +1; 
}
    };
console.log(result1);
```

My console just logs [Function] which makes sense as I have asked it to give me result1, but of course what I wanted was the product of the while loop inside the function there. I know it's an easy one, but I'm just starting out.
Thanks

Comment: You want to _call_ the function.

Comment: The function should also _return_ a value. Also, I think you want to set a variable to the value of `firstOne * timesB`. Otherwise, it has no role in the function.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `firstOne * timesBy;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
var firstOne = 1;
var timesBy = 0;
var result1 = function () {
    while (timesBy < 10) {
        timesBy++;
        firstOne = firstOne * timesBy;
    }
    return firstOne;
};
alert(result1());
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Stb5n/1/)

Comment: I have marked this one as the answer, with no offence meant to David, it's purely that this is the only one I understand :) Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Just a note: updating a global variable (`firstOne`) like this is considered bad practice. It's better to move the declaration of `firstOne` into the `result1` function.

Comment: @Salieri: no offence taken, I'm glad you've found an answer you understand which works for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a value from the function, and call the function itself:

```
var firstOne = 1;
var timesBy = 0;
var result1 = function () {
    while (timesBy < 10) {
        firstOne * timesBy; // does nothing, but I left it regardless.
        timesBy = timesBy + 1;
    }
    return timesBy; // returns the variable back to the calling-context
};
console.log(result1, result1());
//                    ^-- calls the function
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rj8Hq/).

With the updates, in the comments, as to the intended outcome for this function:

```
var firstOne = 1;
var result1 = function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++){
        firstOne = firstOne * i;
    }
    return firstOne;
};
console.log(result1());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rj8Hq/12/).

Comment: Still: what is `firstOne * timesBy;` doing?

Comment: @Jeff: I have no idea, but I assumed the posted code was culled from a larger exercise (and that that particular line was a vestigial remnant).

Comment: If only that were true, hang on I'll write it out

Comment: I was optimistically hoping for result1 timesing firstOne and timesBy together 10 times and then providing me the result, which would then log out to the console.

Comment: looks like the result should be 10 factorial

Comment: That would be better - I was after 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10, but I see that I'm not adding the answers together anyway, even if it had been working in the first place

Comment: Back to the drawing board